# "python manage.py syncdb" not creating tables

Tags: python, django

I first ran

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

and it created the database and tables for me, then I tried to add more apps, and here's what I did:

create apps by

```
python manage.py startapp newapp
```

Then I added `'newapp'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in setting.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'newapp',
)
```

At last I ran `syncdb`:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

and here's the result I get:

```
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

I checked my db and there is no table named `newapp`, no table's name including `newapp`.

Comment: Do you have models in newapp? Please show your models.py.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > somefile.txt
```

You can get quickly check out if your database structure is matching your django models.

Comment: ok, I see that my db structure is not matching my models. how do I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

I also ran into this issue, and was able to get around it by removing the migrations folder inside my app. Somehow that had already gotten created and was tricking syncdb into thinking that it was fully migrated already, but those migration scripts didn't actually do anything useful. Obviously don't try this if you actually have migrations you want to save, but I was working with a brand new app and models.

Comment: I ran into the same issue, deleting the migrations folder allowed syncdb to run against my new app + models.

Comment: It seems that if you comment 'south' from installed apps in the settings file, you can create the whole db

Answer (score 4):

I tried most of the ideas above:

- making sure the `models.py` is imported (verified that the module executed during a makemigrate),
- deleting the `migrations` folder
- setting `managed = True` (this is default anyways),
- used the `python manage.py inspectdb` (which correctly dumped the table, if I had created it manually).

The key was simply to run a `makemigrations` on the *app* separately:

> `python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>`

as part of performing the makemigrations step. Then you do

> `python manage.py migrate`

afterwards as usual.

(applies to Django 1.10, using Postgres 9.5).

[Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#adding-migrations-to-apps)

[Credit, related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259477/table-was-deleted-how-can-i-make-django-recreate-it/37369497#comment66045929_37369497)

Answer (score 1):

i got same problem, but i didn't have any "migration" folder. I solved it like below.

I just added `app_label` with the model code,

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
...
    class Meta:
        managed = True      # add this
        app_label = 'myapp' # & this
```

Also, make sure it is discoverable by referencing it in `myapp/models/__init__.py`

```
from model_file.py import MyModel
```

Comment: The referencing part is **important**

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and noticed that it had created a db.sqlite3 file that didn't seem empty:

```
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r--   1 sauron  staff  122880 Jul 31 01:22 db.sqlite3
```

I tried running sqlite again using the filename as an argument and that worked:

```
$ sqlite3 db.sqlite3 
SQLite version 3.7.13 2012-07-17 17:46:21
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE "auth_group" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(80) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
... many rows ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using this command

```
python manage.py migrate
```

where you were runing syncdb from the location where manage.py resides