# Django - 1051 Unknown table error

Tags: django, database

I accidentally manually dropped a data table. Now when I try to run my project I get an error that says: 1051 Unknown table error.
Is there any way I can fix it it or am I screwed?

Comment: try `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: I did try it, and I get the same error.

Comment: This have happened in production database ?

Comment: mysqlcheck --auto-repair --databases gonegr_db --user=your_username --password

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table was deleted, how can I make Django recreate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259477/table-was-deleted-how-can-i-make-django-recreate-it)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind. 
Goto your app folders and delete all migration files. Delete all tables in the DB. then run migrations and migrate all over again to get your DB refreshed.

OR post the full error message you are getting..

Answer (score 0):

if you faced that same error.that error show because you made changes like creating, deleting, or updating a manual mistake in direct Database or PHPMyAdmin. then this error show like

> MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table
> 'table name' doesn't exist"

in my case, I manually deleted the table in PHPMyAdmin.
solution of error: You directly add the table in PHPMyAdmin and then delete all migration in project_app and add the table class in the model.py file

`python manage.py makemigrations`
o/p: No migrations to apply.

`python manage.py migrate`
o/p: No changes detected

then remove a table in the Model.py file

`python manage.py makemigrations`
o/p: No migrations to apply.

`python manage.py migrate`
o/p: No changes detected

then Add Table Class in the Model.py file

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

o/p: Applying migrations

```
python manage.py migrate
```

o/p:  Create model TableName

definitely you solve this error

Answer (score 0):

Go to the app folder and go inside the folder named migrations, delete the file created with the name of class and then type command :

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also face this error
if you faced that same error.that error show because you made changes like creating, deleting, or updating a manual mistake in direct Database or PHPMyAdmin. then this error show like

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1051, "Unknown table 'school.schooladmin_teacher'")
```

**Solution:**
**Go to the 'App folder' and go inside the folder named 'migrations', delete the file created with the name of class and then type command :**

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

[photo.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Snh3f.png)