# problem: Table doesn't exist( python manage.py migrate)

Tags: django, database-migration

I dropped some table related to an app. and again tried the syncdb command

`python  manage.py migrate`

It shows error like

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'someapp.feed' doesn't exist")
```

models.py

```
class Enroll_course(models.Model):
    SHFE_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Moring'),
        ('E', 'Evening'),
    )
    BATCH_CHOICES = (
        ("A", "1ST"),
        ("B", "2ND")
    )
    userinfo = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    batch = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=BATCH_CHOICES, default="A")
    shife = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SHFE_CHOICES, default="M")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: This post should help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/65547391/13773284

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what happend is that you lost sync with the migration and the db.

Try to delete all the migration related to this table.

(If nothing improtant you can delete all migrations files in the specific app).

Then run `python manage.py makemigrations` - to create all the migrations again.

Then run `python manage.py migrate`